# Can logical operators be used with Cases?

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching, filtering

Suppose I want all two digit primes between -75 and 100 inclusive.

```
a=Range[-75,100]

Select[Select[Cases[a, ?_Positive],(#>9&)],PrimeQ]
```

does it, but can't be the simplest way.

```
Cases[ a, _?Positive] and Cases[a, _?PrimeQ]
```

individually work but

```
Cases[a, _? Positive && PrimeQ]
```

fails, as do most of the variants I could think of using parenthesis and `_?` in from of both `Positive` and `PrimeQ`

Is there an elegant expression and is it possible to use logical operators with `Cases` in the way I am attempting?

Comment: `Select[Range[-75, 100], (Positive[#] && PrimeQ[#] &)]`

Comment: `Select[]` is really much more preferable to `Cases[]` in this case.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Generally I would use [`Condition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Condition.html):

```
Cases[Range[-75, 100], x_ /; Positive[x] && PrimeQ[x]]
```

For the specific case of `And` you can string [`PatternTest`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PatternTest.html) if you control grouping:

```
Cases[Range[-75, 100], (_?Positive)?PrimeQ]
```

> ```
> {2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47,
>  53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97}
> ```

Comment: +1 for `(_?Positive)?PrimeQ`.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard +1 for showing me the use of a double pattern test

Comment: I hope I don't anger my initial responder whose answer was excellent,but Mr Wizard's response has, in my view, the elegant edge so I switched the green check!

Comment: @CMoller the short answer is: no you have not offended me because I am not here only for points. I consider Mr.Wizard as someone who I am learning from, I would suggest you to wait before making an accept. While I may not be here for points but removing accept does damage of points to the other person and shows up on their profile. You may offend someone else.

Comment: @CMoller let's keep it as a lesson for future.

Comment: @CMoller For my part I do not mind losing the check-mark to a better answer posted later.  To discourage that would be to discourage posting of better answers after an Accept has been given, and that would work against everyone's best interest.  Just be sure you don't "move the goalposts" after asking your question; if you receive (and perhaps accept) an answer to the question you asked, but then realize you want something different or more, post a *new* question.

Answer (score 12):

```
Cases[Range[-75, 100], _?(Positive[#] && PrimeQ[#] &)]

(* or *)

Cases[Range[-75, 100], _?(Apply[And, Composition[Positive[#], PrimeQ[#]]] &)]
(* which is the same as the one below*)

Cases[Range[-75, 100], _?(Apply[And, Positive[#1]@*PrimeQ[#1]] &)]

(* or even more compactly *)
Cases[Range[-75, 100], _?(And @@ Positive[#1]@*PrimeQ[#1] &)]
```

a different way with `Cases`:

```
(Cases[#, _?Positive] ⋂ Cases[#, _?PrimeQ]) &@Range[-75, 100]
```

Comment: @CMoller you are very welcome !

Comment: @AliHashmi Since you have expressed interest in my coding style you may wish to see my answer below.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I particularly enjoy your succinct way of coding style. Brief terse and enjoyable to read. I am trying to adopt a coding style which is a hybrid of yours and Leonid. I want to be able to switch to granularity when the need arises however being terse most of the times.

Answer (score 3):

You can use operator forms with [`Select`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Select):

```
Select[
    Range[-75,100],
    Through @* And[Positive, PrimeQ]
]
```

> {2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97}